# How do I replace the built-in wordpress image editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to replace the built-in wordpress image editor (image-edit.php) by way of a plugin. I can't seem to find the correct hook - if there is one. I thought maybe I would replace the wp_image_editor() function, until I remembered you can't overwrite a function in php. So I'm not sure what to do.

Is there such an action hook? If not, what would be the best course of action?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The first course of action is taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask, what not to. Then, the second would be making - and showing us - some research efforts. The third, I would say it's to identify the issue among your attempt, explain desired behavior and then you just need to wait for the answers to come :)

Comment: `wp_image_editor() ` is a class, not a function. Hence you could extend it ?

Answer (score 0):

First , WP_image_editor is a class, not a function ( [CODEX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) )

the filter you are looking for is maybe  `wp_image_editors`

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'image_editors_add_gmagick' );
```

so you would need something like

```
function image_editors_add_gmagick( $editors ) {
    if( ! class_exists('WP_Image_Editor_Gmagick') )
        include_once 'editors/gmagick.php';

    if( ! in_array( 'WP_Image_Editor_Gmagick', $editors ) )
        array_unshift( $editors, 'WP_Image_Editor_Gmagick' );

    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'image_editors_add_gmagick' );
```

This is somewhat of a wild guess, never had to do that myself before ..